# new button context issue while dynamically create

Tags: java, android

Hi i want create dynamically button in android but when i try set context to this i have that issue:
[image]

Here is code:

```
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(result);
for (int i=0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject building = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    Log.i("results", building.optString("name"));
    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText("Push Me");

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buildingLL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll.addView(myButton, lp);
```

}

Anybody can help me with that?

Comment: is it Activity class or other class that is not activity?

Comment: Probably `this` is not context of Activity. Let's try to use `MainActivity.this`
or show more code

Comment: this is in private class WebServiceHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

Comment: ok it helped :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

provide the context from where WebServiceHandler is called & then

```
Button myButton = new Button(mContext); // mContext is the context received on WebServiceHandler class
```

if WebServiceHandler is the private class of any Activity, then

```
Button myButton = new Button(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this);
```